# Extendable class and library

Tags: class

I keep bumping into term "easly extendable" class/library.  I wonder what exectly makes it easy extendable? What must I remember about to create easy extendable classes/libraries? I am interested mainly in .net but any general knowledge will be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, it's that the class/library uses good design practices (in order of importance to me) such as

- Follows [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and it's coherent.
- It's easy to use (I know that this is a very fuzzy term)
- Uses [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) (specially the open/closed principle)
- Depending on what the library tries to solve: that it has good extension points.

And a few other things that I can't remember now :).

Answer (score 1):

Entire books have been written on this subject ... I would start by reading up on the SOLID principles e.g. [here](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).  I would also recommend *Head-First Object-Oriented Analysis & Design* and/or *Head-First Design Patterns* from O'Reilly.